# $http success() not working here

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to splice an item from my list after a delete. The delete works, but the splice doesn't get executed.

The "event" in "success(function(event)" is probably wrong, but not sure what is should be.

```
vm.eventDeleted = function(event) {
    $http.delete('api/events/' + event.eventid).success(function(event){
        vm.events.splice($index, 1);
    }).error(function(err){
        /* do something with errors */
    });
};
```

Comment: How do you know splice isn't executed? are you sure it isn't just not having any effect? where is `$index` coming from?

Comment: I've added a breakpoint (debugging mode) on the splice line (in firefox), and it doesn't stop on it.

Comment: Then it must be instead going to error. What do you get there?

Comment: I don't get it, I see this in err: ""<!DOCTYPE html><html>    <head>        <meta charset="UTF-8" />        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />        <style>            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */

Comment: Copy all that text and paste it into a jsfiddle and run it, you'll see the page being returned. Angular expects json instead unless otherwise specified.

Comment: ok got it, the delete was executed, but the problem was with what I was returning in my controller function. The logic above it working. Thanks guys

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/v6ruo7mj/66/

Make sure you inject $http

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

}]);
```

Comment: I am injecting $http. Should I use "then" instead of "success"?